# How was ChatGPT trained?

Tags: natural-language-processing, chat-bots, training-datasets, language-model, chatgpt

I know that large language models like GPT-3 are trained simply to continue pieces of text that have been scraped from the web. But how was ChatGPT trained, which, while also having a good understanding of language, is not directly a language model, but a chatbot? Do we know anything about that? I presume that a lot of conversations was needed in order to train it. Did they simply scrape those conversations from the web, and where did they find such conversations in that case?

Comment: Can you please focus on one model at a time (either LaMDA or ChatGPT), and ask about the other model in a different post? The answers may change from one model to the other, so it's a good idea to focus, otherwise, you may get different answers, for different ways of training the chatbots, which may be what you're looking for, though.

Comment: @nbro While I would really be interested in knowing about all promising approaches, I chose to focus on ChatGPT since that's the only chatbot that I've personally tried (in recent times at least).

Comment: This article describes it well: ["ChatGPT: How Does It Work Internally?"](https://pub.towardsai.net/chatgpt-how-does-it-work-internally-e0b3e23601a1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key ingredient is called Reinforcement Learning from Human Feedback (RLHF), that is having humans rate the model answers and use the feedback to guide the model training.

[image]

The [official blog](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt/) explains this fairly well.